# In Yggdrasil, which character abilities are most useful/effective?

Tags: yggdrasil

I've played enough [Pandemic](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/30549/pandemic) (another co-operative game with varying player abilities) to know that some characters' abilities are more useful than others, or at least lead to a higher probability of winning.

I've only played [Yggdrasil](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/71671/yggdrasil) a couple of times, but I already wonder if some characters are more likely to win than others. Abilities like being allowed to re-roll dice (Tyr) or +1 to all combat (Thor) seem more useful than, for instance, the ability that lets you use the same action more than once in a turn.

Is this fair? **Are some characters' abilities demonstrably better than others?**

**Edit:** The abilities are:

**Odin**

> Takes two Enemy cards from the stack instead of one, chooses which one he wants to play and puts the other one back on or under the deck.

**Thor**

> Has a permanent +1 bonus for combat.

**Frey**

> Can perform 4 actions during his turn (instead of 3), but they still have to be performed in different worlds.

**Heimdall**

> Can take 4 counters instead of 3 when he looks for souls.

**Tyr**

> Can roll the die twice and choose one of the results in 
>   any situation.

**Freyja**

> Can perform 2 of her 3 actions in the same world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are tiers.

In order of effectiveness and efficiency:

Frey - 33% more actions than any other god, can excel either as pointman, support, or solo, since his play engine is self-sufficient

Thor - always present combat bonus gives great advantage for two worlds, Asgard and Jotunheim; less need for Nidavellir, Alfanheim, and Midgard

Tyr - better combat ability; reroll can affect a number of enemy effects (Fenrir, Jormungand, Hel, Surt); less need for Nidavellir, Alfanheim, and Midgard

Freyja - very situational advantages; otherwise, no direct efficiency bonuses:

-- can upgrade weapons faster than any other god, which lets other gods equip weaker versions on their turn, since gods cannot get equipment unless the next version is available, great for early attacks

-- double Midgard to get over a sunken island on her turn is more cost efficient than using the Vanaheim track

-- double Niflheim to re-distribute elves and vikings quickly

-- can pull off miracle saves for when three enemies cross the line for defeat conditions, by pushing back two enemies on Asgard and then using the Vanaheim track for the third, a feat that not even the mighty fighter Thor can do

Odin - only better if he comes before Tyr in the play order, to manage enemy effects

Heimdall - drains the viking pool too quickly after cleaning the white/blue bag; three enemy effects shut down his power very easily

With fewer players, usefulness of Freyja's ability decreases, usefulness of Frey's ability increases

With more players, usefulness of Frey's ability decreases, usefulness of Freyja's ability increases (due to weapon sharing restrictions)

See this thread on BoardGameGeek titled [The powers of the gods - Odin awfully unmighty? Frey the best of all?](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/659669/the-powers-of-the-gods-odin-awfully-unmighty-fre)

Answer (score 0):

Frejya gets hosed more if he has to deal with Fenrir though, as his ability often requires utilizing it with a 3rd action to make better use of it.

I too like to see Thor in more games than not.

Also, when you add in the Asgard expansion, some of the existing Gods shine when using their Trance ability, as well as interact with the new set of 6 Gods.  Not to mention Trancing was made to deal with the game being more difficult with larger player counts